What is the meaning of וְתֵן חֶלְקֵנוּ בְתוֹרָתֶךָ?
This phrase appears in 5:20 of Ethics of the Fathers and in our siddur.
One translation is "and grant us our portion in Your Torah" (Sefaria)
But I would think we each have the whole Torah.  What is meant by a "portion"?

It states in many sources, including the Alshich's commentary on Shir Hashirim (1:1 iirc), Chesed LeAvraham, Maayan 2, Nahar 12, 18, etc. that every Jew's soul derives from one of the 600,000 letters of Torah. This is interpreted to mean that there are 600,000 perspectives on the entire Torah, each viewing it in their own way. It's also brought (ibid 13) that each Jew has his own Chiddushim to bring into the world, based on his particular perspective. In fact, nobody else can bring YOUR chiddushim, and nobody even knows about it until YOU bring it into the world, even prophets, sages and tzaddikim. The one exception is Moshe, who has all 600,000 perspectives and chiddushim. This is based on Shaar Hagilgulim 17.

Perhaps, it is the same idea as Rabbi Kaii's, although from a different angle. One can also explain the words וְתֵן חֶלְקֵנוּ בְתוֹרָתֶךָ using the Hadran tefilah that we recite at the end of finishing a seder of mishnayos or a masekhes of gemara:

מוֹדִים אֲנַחְנוּ לְּפָנֶיךָ יְיָ אֱלֹהֵינוּ וֶאֱלֹהֵי אַבוֹתֵינוּ שֶׁשַּׂמְתָּ חֶלְקֵנוּ מִיּוֹשְׁבֵי בֵּית הַמִּדְרָשׁ, וְלֹא שַׂמְתָּ חֶלְקֵנוּ מִיּוֹשְׁבֵי קְרָנוֹת. שֶׁאָנוּ מַשְׁכִּימִים וְהֵם מַשְׁכִּימִים. אָנוּ מַשְׁכִּימִים לְדִבְרֵי תּוֹרָה וְהֵם מַשְׁכִּימִים לִדְבָרִים בְּטֵלִים. אָנוּ עֲמֵלִים וְהֵם עֲמֵלִים. אָנו עֲמֵלִים וּמְקַבְּלִים שָׂכָר וְהֵם עֲמֵלִים וְאֵינָם מְקַבְּלִים שָׂכָר. אָנוּ רָצִים וְהֵם רָצִים. אָנוּ רָצִים לְחַיֵּי הָעוֹלָם הַבָּא, וְהֵם רָצִים לִבְאֵר שַׁחַת. שֶׁנֱאמַר: וְאַתָּה אֱלֹהִים תּוֹרִדֵם לִבְאֵר שַׁחַת אַנְשֵׁי דָמִים וּמִרְמָה לֹא יֶחֱצוּ יְמֵיהֶם וַאֲנִי אֶבְטַח בָּךְ:
We give thanks before You, Lord, our G-d and G-d of our fathers, for you gave us a share among those who sit in the study hall, and not among those who sit on street corners. For we arise early, and they arise early; we arise for words of Torah, and they arise for words of emptiness. We work, and they work; we work and receive a reward, and they work and do not receive a reward. We run, and they run; we run towards eternal life, and they run to a pit of desolation. As it says: (Psalms 55:24) "And You, O Lord, bring them down into a pit of desolation, people of blood and deceit will not live out half of their days; and I, I will trust in You."

As the prayer explains, the Jewish person oftentimes does all the same activities as anybody else. However, the intent of every action is to identify and perform a rooted in it mitzvah, building a relationship with HKBH. Thus, getting a portion in the Torah, is also a request to connect and reframe one's acquired daily wisdom in the language of our wonderful heritage of the Torah of the Jewish people.
